# Update header after login on GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I try to update my GraphQL headers on login success. I use Apollo.

My default settings is this :

```
const { API_GRAPHQL_URL } = config;

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: API_GRAPHQL_URL
});

const getToken = async () => await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = await getToken();

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
    }
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

But, if i'm not logged, the token is null. On login success, i would like update my header, or refresh, for load the token saved on localstorage (using React-Native).

Anyone know if an middleware exist or other solution ?

Thank you community !

Comment: Can you show us where you set the token after the login mutation?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the job of your `getToken` function? If `getToken` returns a token, then the auth header will be set, if not it won't, and that's exactly what you want. Wherever you save your token after logging in (cookie/session, localStorage), that's where `getToken` will need to read it from.